# Complete graph not embeddable in $H(n,2)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and consider $x,y \in\{0,1\}^n$. The *Hamming distance* of $x,y$ is defined by $$d_H(x,y) = |\{i\in \{0,\ldots, n-1\}:x_i\neq y_i\}|.$$

For $n\geq 2$ let $H(n,2)$ be the graph given by the vertex set $\{0,1\}^n$ and the edge set $$\big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y\in \{0,1\}^n \land d_H(x,y) \leq 2\big\}.$$

**Question.** Is every finite complete graph a subgraph of $H(n,2)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

---

I am sure that $K_3$ is in $H(n,2)$ but it seems that $K_4$ is not.

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: I am sure $K_3$ works but it seems that $K_4$ doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $H(n,2)$ all the vertex which are strings with one $1$ are at Hamming distance $2$ from each other. The subgraph they generate is $K_n$.

Comment: And if you add the all zero string, which is at hamming distance 1 from the others, then you find an embedding of $K_{n+1}$ in $H(n,2)$.